# Refresh Kendo Grid after close of pop up window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI Web for asp.net mvc.  I generate a pop-up window via a grid command button.  After the closing of this pop-up window, I want the grid to be refreshed.

Close event on pop-up window:

```
function ClosingRateWindow(e) {
    var grid = $('#ContractDetailOrderEventGrid').data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.read();}
```

The grid is undefined at this time.

Kendo Window definition:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("Rates")
    .Title("Rates")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(850)
    .Height(1200)
    .Events(x => x.Close("ClosingRateWindow"))
)
```

Javascript to open window (a partial view is returned):

```
wnd.refresh({
    url: BASE_APP_URL + "ContractRateAdmin/OpenContractRate/",
    data: { data: data },
    traditional: true
});
wnd.center();
wnd.open();
```

Grid Definition:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TMS.MVC.TIMS.Models.Admin.Contract.ContractOrderEventGridModel>()
.Name("ContractDetailOrderEventGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Command(o =>
    {
        o.Destroy();
        o.Edit();
    }).Width(100).Title("Commands");

    columns.Command(command => 
        { 
            command.Custom("Rates").Click("ShowRates");
        }).Title("Rates").Width(120);
    columns.Bound(o => o.ContractId).Hidden(true);
    columns.Bound(o => o.OrderTypeId).Hidden(true);
    //columns.Bound(o => o.ActiveRateMissing).Width(70).Title("Missing Rates?");
    columns.Bound(o => o.OrderLevelFlag).Width(50).Title("Order Level").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_OrderLevelFlag");
    columns.Bound(o => o.Active).Width(80).Title("Active").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_Active");
    columns.Bound(o => o.InvoiceDescription).Width(150).Title("Invoice Desc");
    columns.Bound(o => o.SourceContainerOwnerNameDisplay).Width(150).Title("Src Cont Owner").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_SourceContainerOwner");
    columns.Bound(o => o.DestContainerOwnerNameDisplay).Width(150).Title("Dest Cont Owner").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_DestContainerOwner");
    columns.Bound(o => o.SourceContainerTypeName).Width(150).Title("Src Cont Type").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_SourceContainerTypeName");
    columns.Bound(o => o.DestContainerTypeName).Width(150).Title("Dest Cont Type").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_DestContainerTypeName");
    columns.Bound(o => o.SourceContainerName).Width(150).Title("Src Container").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_SourceContainerName");
    columns.Bound(o => o.DestContainerName).Width(150).Title("Dest Container").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_DestContainerName");
    columns.Bound(o => o.EventAliasName).Width(150).Title("Event").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_EventAliasName");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ProductName).Width(150).Title("Product").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_ProductName");
    columns.Bound(o => o.OrderByNameDisplay).Width(150).Title("Order By").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_OrderBy");
    columns.Bound(o => o.OrderTypeName).Width(150).Title("Order Type").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_OrderTypeName");
    columns.Bound(o => o.EmployeeDisplay).Width(150).Title("Employee").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_EmployeeDisplay");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CarrierName).Width(150).Title("Carrier").EditorTemplateName("ContractOE_CarrierName");
})
    .Events(e => e
        .Save("Contract_Save")
        //.Remove("ContractOrderEventGrid_Remove")
        .DataBound("Contract_DataBound"))
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true).Height("300px"))
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>  {
            if (Model.DetailModel.ContractAdminDetailPermissionModel.AddOrderEvent_Button_Visible == true)
                toolbar.Create().Text("Add");
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 1200px" })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
    .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(false))
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
    .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))
    .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ContractOrderEventId);
            model.Field(x => x.ActiveRateMissing).Editable(false);
            model.Field(x => x.ContractId).Editable(false);
            model.Field(x => x.OrderTypeId).Editable(false);
            model.Field(x => x.Active).Editable(true).DefaultValue("Y");
            model.Field(x => x.OrderLevelFlag).Editable(true).DefaultValue("N");
            model.Field(x => x.InvoiceDescription).Editable(true).DefaultValue("Enter Invoice Description");
            model.Field(x => x.SourceContainerOwnerNameDisplay).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.DestContainerOwnerNameDisplay).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.SourceContainerTypeName).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.DestContainerTypeName).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.SourceContainerName).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.DestContainerName).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.EventAliasName).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.ProductName).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.OrderByNameDisplay).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.OrderTypeName).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.EmployeeDisplay).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
            model.Field(x => x.CarrierName).Editable(true).DefaultValue("ALL");
        })
           .Events(x =>
           {
              // x.RequestEnd("RefreshContractDetailOrderEventGrid");
               //x.Error("ContractDetailOrderEventGrid_Error");
           })
       .Create(update => update.Action("CreateContractOrderEvent", "ContractGrid", new { selectedContractId = Model.DetailModel.ContractId }))
       .Read(read => read.Action("ReadContractOrderEvent", "ContractGrid", new { contractId = Model.DetailModel.ContractId }))
       .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateContractOrderEvent", "ContractGrid", new { contractId = Model.DetailModel.ContractId }))
       .Destroy(update => update.Action("DestroyContractOrderEvent", "ContractGrid"))
    ))
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to use the [close](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#events-close) event of the Window and the refresh method of the Grid or I guess you need to use the dataSource.read() method which will refresh the data of the Grid :)

```
wnd.bind('close',function(){
    $('#Rates').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read(); // or
    $('#Rates').data().kendoGrid.refresh();
})
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing.  The grid is undefined though inside the close function.  Probably due to it no existing in the pop-up window put the grid that initiated it.

Comment: How come it is undefined? If it is visible( it is initialized) you should be able to access it.

Comment: The grid is not on the Rates pop-up window.  The pop-up window is initiated from a button on this grid that I want updated.  At the time of pop-up close, the grid is undefined as far as I can tell since I can't reference as per normal in javascript.   $('#ContractDetailOrderEventGrid').data("kendoGrid");

Answer (score 2):

The `grid` variable is undefined in the popup, because it is defined in the parent window;
so you need to do the following:

```
var grid = window.parent.$("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

\I do see a lot of responses here concerned with the undefined error. I am attempting to do the same thing here. My resolution to the issue was to attach a function to the close event of the editor window.:

```
.Editable(a => a.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).Window(q => q.Title("New Stage").Events(e => e.Close("UpdateStages"))))
```

And then the function that is called is:

```
function UpdateStages() {
    $("#StagesForCourse").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}
```

I dont worry about trying to take in the variable, instead i call the grid directly and tell it to read the dataSource

Answer (score 1):

Can you try;

```
function ClosingRateWindow(e) {
    var grid = $('#ContractDetailOrderEventGrid').data("kendoGrid");
    grid.refresh();
}
```

Comment: The variable grid is undefined.

Comment: Can you post your grid definition.

Comment: I've added the grid definition to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is probably late. But if you are getting content from another URL. You need to set .Iframe(true). Found this out after hours of debugging. They really have very poor documentation on this.